# FFmpeg can't access file in Dropbox on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, video, ffmpeg, ubuntu-12.04, dropbox

I have installed FFmpeg on Ubuntu 12.04. When I use `ffmpeg -i` command to check some video file online, it works:

```
ffmpeg -i http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4
```

However, when I check a public file hosted in my Dropbox it gives 'No such file or directory error':

```
ffmpeg -i https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/51617581/bigbuck.webm
```

and the error is:

> https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/51617581/bigbuck.webm: No such
>   file or directory

and here is the version info of the ffmpeg installation:

> ffmpeg version 0.8.17-4:0.8.17-0ubuntu0.12.04.1, Copyright (c)
>   2000-2014 the Libav developers   built on Mar 16 2015 13:26:50 with
>   gcc 4.6.3

I have also tried both files on my Mac 10.10 laptop, and both of them work fine. Could anyone suggest where is the problem? Many thanks.

Comment: Works fine on my end with ffmpeg 2.7.1. Your version is outdated and I'd recommend upgrading. You can still try to access the non-secured url (remove the 's' from 'https'), maybe that's what is causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In short: You are using the [fake ffmpeg](http://blog.pkh.me/p/13-the-ffmpeg-libav-situation.html), you must switch to the [real one](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu).

Comment: Thanks. I have tried to install the real one following the guide. But it seems my Ubuntu version is too old and many packages just refuse to install. For example, I got the following message when I try to install libass-dev:

You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
libass-dev : Depends: libass4 (= 0.10.0-3) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libenca-dev but it is not going to be installed
              ...
linux-image-server : Depends: linux-image-3.2.0-86-generic but it is not going to be installed